# How can I return this object to its original position based on the camera view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In this code, I get the first position of the `test` and store it in `originalPos` so that whenever I do a left click, the `test` will return to its original position.
The problem I'm facing with this is that the camera is following wherever the test is going; I want it to return to its position based on the camera view, but it just returns to its original position based on, I think, world coordinates.
I haven't shown in this code how the test changes its position. But when I change its position and try to left-click, it wants to return to the position based on the world coordinates.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class WalkParent : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject test;
    Vector3 originalPos;
    [SerializeField] private Camera mainCamera;  
    void Start()
    {
        test = GameObject.FindWithTag("TT");
        originalPos = test.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {



            test.transform.position = originalPos;

        }



    }

}
```

I tried these, and they didn't work for me:

```
 originalPos = mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(test.transform.position);
 originalPos = mainCamera.WorldToViewportPoint(test.transform.position);
 originalPos = mainCamera.ScreenToWorldPoint(test.transform.position);
 originalPos = mainCamera.ViewportToWorldPoint(test.transform.position);
 originalPos = mainCamera.ScreenToViewportPoint(test.transform.position);
 originalPos = mainCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(test.transform.position);
```

The problem with `originalPos = mainCamera.ViewportToScreenPoint(test.transform.position);` was that I run the game and then don't change the position of the test, but when I do a left click, the test moves somewhere else. I want it to be fixed in its own position, like the position that it had at the beginning of the game in front of my eye.

I want this `originalPos = test.transform.position;` to be a fixed position on the camera veiw. So that `test` would always return there.

Comment: so you want it to return to a position in a direction/distance from the camera? so even if the camera has moved 50m forward, if the item was 2m to the right and 1m forward you now want that item to return to 2m to the right and 1m forward?

Comment: @BugFinder I think I shouldn't have said camera. Maybe I meant the screen of the game. I'm talking about that 2D rectangle. I want the object to return a position from a direction or distance from the frame that the game is inside of. I want to set the position based on something fixed that never changes if the camera moves or the object moves. I guess it is the screen or the frame of the game.

Comment: I think you're using all the wrong words as its not making sense.

Comment: @BugFinder Thank you. So I created an object where I wanted my test to be if I had done a left-click. Then, in the script inside Fire1, I made their positions the same, and it worked. I literally wasted two or more days on this!

Comment: Since you record the position in `Start` with `transform.position`, the camera is irrelivant (unless I've missed the point of the question). `test.transform.position = originalPos` should work fine, however is the object parented to something? If so try `test.transform.localPosition = originalPos`. See https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html

Comment: @Absinthe Yes, it has a parent. I was always wondering why, when I set it's position to  `Vector3(0, 0, 0);` it was acting weird. I had to use the `localPosition` :  `test.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);` So if you answer the question, I'll accept your answer. I don't need the `originalPos` anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments when an object is parented the position of it is relative to it's parent rather than `Vector3.zero` because it includes it's parent's position, so in these cases it's best to use `localPosition` in case the parent isn't at zero. For example if the parent is at (0, 0, 10), the child will add the Z 10 to it's position.